# lru-cache npm module not working correctly

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

Im running this my app and i included a module called "mysql2" in my app and when i installed it properly and run it, it shows this error:

```
root@ubuntu:/var/www/compti# npm start

 compti@0.0.0 start

 nodemon app.js

[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
/var/www/compti/node_modules/mysql2/node_modules/lru-cache/dist/cjs/index.js:359
    #initializeTTLTracking() {
                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/compti/node_modules/mysql2/node_modules/lru-cache/dist/cjs/index-cjs.js:5:36)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Im running it in a ubuntu vm its running perfectly fine in other linux vm.

Tried different kind of stuff like reinstalling, installing latest etc.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

what i did to fix my issue ?

Make sure I have the lastest version of mysql2 and also lru-cache.

I import lru -cache like this

```
import { LRUCache } from 'lru-cache'
```

and i import mysql2 like this

```
import pkg from 'mysql2';
const mysql = pkg;
```